# Update from 6.35 to 6.37 No errors but still showing as 6.35

Tags: updating

I read the other questions on here and I've searched google for an answer but without luck. I don't have SSH access to the server so I'm stuck updating the site manually. I used the process explained on [How To Update Drupal Core](https://www.drupal.org/node/1494290) on drupal.org.

#### Quick synopsis

- Backup
- Maintenance mode
- Delete old files on server (not /sites)
- Copy in NEW files
- Run update.php
- Take out of Maintenance mode

There were NO errors when the update finished and no issues with the site. When I check in the admin (under available updates) it still says 6.35 with  6.37 as the recommended update.

How can I fix this?